# request getParameter for Text returning null

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to Java servlets. I am creating an html page using the servlets. Among the different fields, I have a textbox field where I am displaying the elapsed time. The code for that is here:

```
<input type="text" size="15" disabled="disabled" hidden="true" name="finalduration">
```

I have a Javascript file that calculates and enters the value for "finalduration" textbox and makes it hidden="false", once the submission button is pressed.

However, back in the servlet, I am trying to process the value entered by the javascript, I get a "null". The code on the servlet, I am using to obtain the value is:

```
durationBar = (String)request.getParameter("finalduration");
```

The idea is, the javascript calculates the elapsed time, enters the elapsed time (or duration) in the "finalduration" box, and my servlet should process that value and enter into the database. I am being able to read other values from this page (which are in combo boxes, drop down lists, etc), and this one is the only value that I am not being able to get.

Any ideas how to handle this?

**EDIT** 
I removed the "disabled" and it works now.

The idea that I am trying to implement here is a timer bar. Person comes to my site, clicks on "start time", the timer starts and is displayed on screen. During the time when the timer is running, the "finalduration" is hidden. Once the person clicks on "stop timer", the duration is calculated using javascript and the final duration is shown on the page with the "finalduration" text field. That's the reason why I want to implement in such a manner that the user can't edit the finalduration, as it would defeat the purpose of calculating the duration.

Any ideas regarding how to implement that, would be appreciated.

Comment: Is their a `form` around your `input` ?

Comment: your `finalduration` must be inside a `form` with the action pointing to your servlet

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. All this code is inside the "form" tag pointing to the servlet. That's how I am getting the values from other elements, except from this one.

Comment: @user1244329 i don't know but could "disabled" be the reason that input is not retrieved by the servlet?

Comment: @deporter you were right! I removed the "disabled" and it works.

Comment: But, now the next step would be set it up such a way that the user can't modify the "finalduration" value - would defeat the purpose of calculating the duration if the user can modify it. Any ideas, other than using the "disabled" method?

Comment: @user1244329 Well, "normal" users can't modify hidden fields as they're not displayed. "Advanced" users on the other hand can submit whatever they want, so if you want this field value to be secure, don't calculate it on the client side.

Comment: @biziclop I will try calculating on the server side. Essentially, the "hidden" is set back to "true" once the user clicks on something.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question, do not change an old and answered question.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled form fields are not submitted by user agents [according to the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1). Just remove the `disabled` attribute (it doesn't make much sense for hidden fields anyway) and it should work.

**Update**: As it was pointed out, you're not hiding the field correctly. The correct markup would be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="finalduration">
```

However, as I already said, users can still potentially modify the value and submit whatever value they want. Do *not* use hidden fields (or any other form fields) for storing values that you don't want malicious users to modify.

Comment: @deporter I'm sorry, your comment wasn't there when I started writing my answer. In any case, at least now there's a reference to the relevant spec too.